# How not trigger the animation when change Theme

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, material-ui

I`m working on a little game, basically like this: https://sweardle.com/ and i have a dark theme and a light theme, I have, too, some animations that triggers when the Api sends the response (the div flip while change the background color if you match a letter). The problem: if i change the theme to dark/light ALL application is remounted what makes all animations retrigger. What can i do to change the theme from dark to light or light to dark whitout trigger the animation again?
My application is using ReactJS and MUIV5

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you implement your dark / light theme.
I think the best way would be for you to use css variables to style your elements.
Then when you change the theme you can just toggle some kind of `theme="light"` on your html element (or save / read a value from local storage), which in turn will update your css.

Example:

```css
html[data-theme='light'] {
    --background-color: white;
    --text-color: blue;
}

html[data-theme='dark'] {
    --background-color: black;
    --text-color: yellow;
}

.your-element {
    background-color: var(--background-color);
    color: var(--text-color);
}
```

Maybe this [here](https://lukelowrey.com/css-variable-theme-switcher/) can also help you